# Adding Booking Calendar to Wordpress.com Site

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api, wordpress.com

As a disclaimer, I am totally new to wordpress, but not web programming.  An acquaintance has asked me to add a booking calendar to their wordpress.com site.  The calendar would allow a user to select a date for their appointment, fill out a little signup form, and then save that to be viewed by site admins.

At first glance, I thought I could just use one of the many Booking Calendar plugins available on wordpress.org.  However, I realize now that these plugins are not available for wordpress.com. I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, has anyone done something similar for a wordpress site?

Is there anyway to use Google Calendar Events widget to allow site visitors to add their event to the calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which features you want, Google Calendar integration might suffice. It's one of the built-in plugins available on wordpress.com:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/

Otherwise, if more custom features are needed, you might want to consider hosting elsewhere. Most shared hosting environments these days offer WordPress as an easy install, and there are some specialized hosting environment built specifically for WordPress, such as WP Engine or Dreamhost's WordPress hosting package. By hosting elsewhere, you'd have access to a more robust plugin environment and likely be able to find what you need. However, migrating has it's own headaches, as you have to change the URL references in the database. This might be straightforward for you though depending on your background.